# How to start a virtual keyboard without losing focus in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, keyboard, focus

I need to start a virtual keyboard from my application (namely click-n-type) to allow user input in the active field.

When I use the `start click-n-type.exe` the keyboard starts normally but I lose the focus. When I use `start /min click-n-type.exe`, I keep the focus but the keyboard is minimized.

Is there a way to have both my focus unchanged and virtual keyboard in its place?

Comment: This looks like stackoverflow question

Answer (score 0):

Click-N-Type Version 3.03.402 and later does not take focus when it starts.